# wxPython: Path problems when exporting a bitmap

Tags: python, path, wxpython

I have a module which starts a wxPython app, which loads a `wx.Bitmap` from file for use as a toolbar button. It looks like this: `wx.Bitmap("images\\new.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)`. All works well when I run that module by itself, but when I try to import and run it from a different module which is in a different directory, wxPython raises an exception. (The exception is something internal regarding the toolbar, which I think just means it's not loading the bitmap right.)

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"images\new.png" is a relative path, so when bitmap gets loaded it will depened what is the cur dir
so either you set cur dir

```
os.chdir("location to images folder")
```

or 
have a function which loads relative to your program e.g.

```
def getProgramFolder():
    moduleFile = __file__
    moduleDir = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(moduleFile))[0]
    programFolder = os.path.abspath(moduleDir)
    return programFolder

bmpFilePath = os.path.join(getProgramFolder(), "images\\new.png")
```

Comment: Is this standard practice when making an application with wxPython?

Comment: I will say this is standard practice in any application you want to use relative paths, somewhere you must tell what is this relative too

Comment: else you can embed image into app, but you loose flexibility during development,

Answer (score 1):

The [wxPython FAQ](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions#head-f3905e355271308d301310f0f8c1af64833ed912) recommends using a tool called `img2py.py` to embed icon files into a Python module. This tool comes with the wxPython distribution.

Here is an [example of embedding toolbar icons](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WorkingWithToolBars).